# Type narrowing a discriminated union without if or switch

Tags: typescript

I'd like to do type narrowing with a key on an object. Example:

```
class TextNode {
  readonly type = 'text_node';
}

class ImageNode {
  readonly type = 'image_node';
  url: string;
}

type MarkupNode = TextNode | ImageNode;

type Hook<Type extends MarkupNode['type']> = (node: { type: Type }) => { type: Type };

type Hooks = { [NodeType in MarkupNode['type']]?: Hook<NodeType> };

const hooks: Hooks = {
  image_node: node => { // I'd like node to be an ImageNode
    node.url = 'https://images.com/the-image';
    return node;
  },
};
```

This of course results in the error `Property 'url' does not exist on type '{ type: "text_node"; }'`. The offending line is `type Hook<Type> = (node: { type: Type }) => { type: Type };`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to extract the correct `MarkupNode` type here.

Maybe there's a helper function that I need to wrap the hooks object in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you want but in you mapped type you will need to use the `Extract` conditional type to extract the apropriate member of the union:

```
class TextNode {
    readonly type = 'text_node';
}

class ImageNode {
    readonly type = 'image_node';
    url: string;
}

type MarkupNode = TextNode | ImageNode;

type Hook<TNode> = (node: TNode) => TNode;

type Hooks = { [NodeType in MarkupNode['type']]?: Hook<Extract<MarkupNode, { type: NodeType }>> };

const hooks: Hooks = {
    image_node: node => { // is now ImageNode
        node.url = 'https://images.com/the-image';
        return node;
    },
};
```

The `Extract` conditional type will extract the type of the union with the same `type` as the `type` specified in the second type parameter.